# When i click on a button in android app it takes long time to response

Tags: android

I have a problem that i have a 4 buttons with XML style in the same layout, When i run the app and hit a button it take about 3 second to response then all buttons response instantly.

All 4 buttons have a very simple Onclick code that's apply another XML code to the other 3 buttons.

Onclick code **the same for all 4 buttons** :

```
answer1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            numberClicked++;
            if(trueanswernumber == 1)
            trueanswer = true;
            else trueanswer = false;
            answer1.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.answerclicked));
            answer2.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.answerbutton));
            answer3.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.answerbutton));
            answer4.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.answerbutton));
        }
    });
```

"answerclicked" XML code :

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="5dip" />
         <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#6f1864" />

     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="5dip" />
         <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#6f1864" />
         <solid  android:color="#125156"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>  
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#ffffff" />

     </shape>
 </item>
```

"answerbutton" xml code :

```
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="5dip" />
         <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#ffffff" />

     </shape>
 </item>
<item android:state_focused="true">
     <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="5dip" />
         <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#ffffff" />
         <solid  android:color="#125156"/>       
     </shape>
 </item>  
<item >
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
         <corners android:radius="3dip" />
         <stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#363636" />

     </shape>
 </item>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you post your layout, please?

Comment: We need more information, to help you Thaer. Edit your question and past your onClick code and XML into it, so we can see what your are doing. Otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Added please check again